# Testing Express / Passport middleware using Jasmine — passport.authenticate never completes

Tags: node.js, express, jasmine, passport.js, gulp-jasmine

I'm trying to unit test a simple piece of Express middleware, a cascading athenticator that checks first for a JWT token using a `passport-jwt-strategy`, and then if that fails, using a `passport-openid-strategy`.  Each of the strategies is already well tested so what I am trying to test is their integration.

The module I am testing looks like this:

```js
"use strict";

let passport = require('passport');
let Strategies = require('./strategies');
let setupDone = false;

// set up passport
let setup = function (app) {
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
        done(null, obj);
    });

    passport.use('jwt', Strategies.jwt);
    passport.use('openid', Strategies.openId);
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    setupDone = true;
};

let authenticate = function (req, res, next) {
    if (!setupDone) throw new Error('You must have run setup(app) before you can use the middleware');
    console.log(' cascadingAuthentication');
    // first try the token option
    passport.authenticate('jwt', function (jwterr, user, info) {
        console.log(' jwt auth', jwterr, user, info);
        if (jwterr || !user) {
            passport.authenticate('openid', function (oautherr, user, info) {
                if (oautherr || !user) {
                    return next(oautherr);
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            });
        } else {
            req.user = user;
            next();
        }
    });
};

module.exports = {
    setup: setup,
    authenticate: authenticate
}
```

My `Jasmine` test looks like this

```js
"use strict";

let CascadingAuthentication = require('../../lib/middleware/cascadingAuthentication');
let TokenUtils = require('../support/tokenUtils');
let email = 'testing@test.tes';

describe('cascadingAuthentication', function () {

    describe('when there is a token in the header', function () {
        let req;
        let res = {};
        let app = {
            use: function (used) { console.log('app.use called with', typeof used); }
        };

        beforeEach(function (done) {
            let token = TokenUtils.makeJWT(email);
            req = {
                app: app,
                header: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            }
            CascadingAuthentication.setup(app);
            CascadingAuthentication.authenticate(req, res, function () {
                done();
            });
        });

        it('populates req.user', function () {
            expect(req.user).toEqual(jasmine.any(Object));
        });
    });

});
```

The issue I have is that, when I run the test, I see the first `console.log(' cascadingAuthentication')` but I never see the second `console.log('jwt auth', err, user, info)`. The code just dies inside `passport.authenticate` without ever calling the callback, without raising an error, or without providing any kind of feedback at all.

I'm running my tests via `gulp` using `Jasmine`.

My questions are: in order,

1. Can you see anything obvious that I have done that I might have just missed?
2. Is there anything else I ought to mock out in my `req`, `res`, or `app` that might make this test work?
3. Is there any way to debug this interactively; stepping through the code under test as it runs, rather than just adding `console.log` statements (which seems a little 1980s to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging through `passport`'s source I have worked out there were two problems with my code.

The first is that `passport.authenticate` returns a middleware function, it doesn't actually execute that function.  So the solution was simply to call the returned function.

So my authenticate method now looks like:

```
let authenticate = function(req, res, next) {
  if (!setupDone) throw new Error('You must have run setup(app) before you can use the middleware');
  // first try the token option
  passport.authenticate('jwt', function(jwterr, user, info) {
    if (jwterr || !user) {
      passport.authenticate('openid', function(autherr, user, info) {
        if (autherr || !user) {
          return next(autherr);
        } else {
          next();
        }
      })(req, res, next);
    } else {
      req.user = user;
      next();
    }
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

(The above example is trimmed for use in the question)

The other issue was in my test I used `header` instead of `headers` in my mock `req` object, and also `authorization` ought to have had a lower case `a`.

With those two fixes the test now passes.

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled with this for quite some time and eventually landed on the following setup (to test `passport.authenticate('local', () => {})`).

**auth-router.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');

const login = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
      return;
    }

    if (!user) {
      const error = new Error(info.message);
      error.status = 404;
      next(error);
      return;
    }

    // Add the found user record to the request to 
    // allow other middlewares to access it.
    req.user = user;
    next();
  })(req, res, next);
};

const router = express.Router();
router.post('/auth/login', login);

module.exports = {
  login,
  router
};
```

**auth-router.spec.js**

```js
const passport = require('passport');

describe('login', () => {
  it('should login and add the user to the request object', (done) => {
    spyOn(passport, 'authenticate').and.callFake((strategy, callback) => {
      const err = null;
      const user = {};
      const info = {};
      callback(err, user, info);
      return (req, res, next) => {};
    });

    const auth = require('./auth'); // my middleware function
    const req = { body: {} };
    const res = {};
    const next = () => {
      expect(req.user).toBeDefined();
      done();
    };

    auth.login(req, res, next);
  });
});
```